# Qt- checking regular expression width

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm trying to replace regular expression with different expression which depend on width of line and width of box.

Here is my code:

```
//mangledText is my text that I've searching on it
//rx is regular expression
QRegExp rx("<lms([^<]*)/>");
    while ((pos = rx.indexIn(mangledText)) != -1){
     for (int j = 0; j < tempLayout->lineCount(); j++){         
        QTextLine tl = tempLayout->lineAt(j);
            //here is width of each line        
        int naturalTextWidth = tl.naturalTextWidth();
            //rect width is maximum width of box
        if (naturalTextWidth < rectWidth)
            mangledText.replace(pos, rx.matchedLength(), "replace Text");
        else
            mangledText.replace(pos, rx.matchedLength(), "\n replace Text");             
    }
}
mangledText.replace('\n', QChar::LineSeparator);
```

I want to replace regular expression with "\n replace Text"  if text on that line is out of box. otherwise I replace it with "replace Text" . Problem is it will always shift it to next line. because `rectWidth` is smaller that `naturalTextWidth`. but I want to check an each regular expression to replace.

**UPDATED:**
For example :
111111111111111111111111111`<lms8><lms3><lms2>`

is showing :

111111111111111111111111111
`<lms8>`
`<lms3>`
`<lms2>`

and I want this:

111111111111111111111111111
`<lms8><lms3><lms2>`

Any suggestion?

Comment: yes, I did it. rectWidth is constant integer.

Comment: Could you show some text and what you actually want to do it with it? I fail to understand what you are after here :)

Comment: I've updated my question @ChristianRapp

Comment: It looks like you're just implementing word wrapping with specific boundaries. I don't see an option for this in QTextOptions/QTextLayout

Comment: Perhaps matching all consecutive tags in 1 attempt: `"(?:<lms[^<>]*/>)+"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
(.[^<]*)(<lms.*>)
```

Replace with following syntax.

```
$1\n$2
```

The result would be

`111111111111111111111111111
<lms8><lms3><lms2>`